# Inserting Values into Temp Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me to work out below T-SQL code. I am facing issue while adding the second value. The first value gives the state of SQL Service and second value gives the SQL last restart time. I am not a core developer so can anyone help me .

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
drop table tempdb..#temp1

create table #temp1 
([Current Service State] nvarchar(200),
[SQL_Server_last_RestartOn]nvarchar(200))

insert into  #temp1
EXEC master.sys.xp_servicecontrol N'querystate',N'MSSQLSERVER',
(select min(login_time) from master..sysprocesses) as SQL_Server_last_RestartOn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#temp1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp1

CREATE TABLE #temp1 (
    [Current Service State] NVARCHAR(200)
    ,[SQL_Server_last_RestartOn] NVARCHAR(200)
    )

INSERT INTO #temp1 ([Current Service State])
EXEC master.sys.xp_servicecontrol N'querystate'
    ,N'MSSQLSERVER'

UPDATE #temp1
SET SQL_Server_last_RestartOn = (
        SELECT min(login_time)
        FROM master..sysprocesses
        )

SELECT *
FROM #temp1
```

Comment: ,I am getting this error : Invalid column name Current Service State

Comment: What version of Sql Server are you using?  I just copied my answer into a blank query windows running Sql 2008 and it ran fine without any errors.

Comment: I am using sql server 2014

Comment: I just ran my answer on 2014 and it ran fine without any errors.  Update you question with the 'exact' query you're trying now.

Comment: I just re ran it it was successful,Thanks a lot @Scott Hodgin